# How to play audio buffers using `AVCapturesession` in `didOutputSampleBuffer`

Tags: ios, avfoundation, playback, avcapturesession

I have been trying to play audio which is received as raw data in `didOutputSampleBuffer` delegate. What should be the proper way to process the raw data?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following sample code from Apple: [AVCaptureTtoAudioUnitOSX](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCaptureToAudioUnit/Introduction/Intro.html)

There you can see how to properly process the raw audio data and pass it to the `AudioUnit`.

The basic principle is as follows:

1. Get the `SampleBuffer`'s `AudioStreamBasicDescription` for info on format

   First get the `CMFormatDescriptionRef` with `CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription`

   Then get the `AudioStreamBasicDescription` with `CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription`

   Now you can get info on sample rate, bits per channel, channels per frame and frames per packet
2. Get the `AudioBufferList` with the actual audio data

   Either use CoreAudio's Public Utility or check this [mailing list](http://prod.lists.apple.com/archives/quicktime-api/2013/Apr/msg00015.html) entry for a correct way of doing so

   The function is called `CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer`. Third parameter is the `bufferListOut` which is the `AudioBufferList` you want and will pass on to work with e.g. the AudioUnit or whatever your need is.
3. Getting the actual raw data

   The `AudioBufferList` contains `AudioBuffers` each of which contain the data

   ```
   struct AudioBuffer {
    UInt32 mNumberChannels;
    UInt32 mDataByteSize;
    void   *mData;
   };
   ```

This should get you going. Look at the sample code from Apple for more info.